# WARNING discord.ext.commands.bot Privileged message content intent is missing, commands may not work as expected

Tags: python, discord.py

How do I resolve this warning, my bot isn't able to function correctly with this error.

I changed my base code to this, thinking it would solve the problem but the problem still persists.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents(guilds=True, messages=True)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True
intents.guilds = True
intents.messages = True
intents.reactions = True
intents.presences = True
intents.message_content = True
```

Comment: You create instance of bot before setting up the intents...

Answer (score 1):

Just define the client after enabling the intents...

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```

Also no need to add every intent explicitly, you already enabled *all* intents.

Answer (score 1):

go into your developer portal or by clicking on this link: https://discord.com/developers/applications
then click on your bot application and go into the "bot" section. Scroll down and there you would see all the "intents". Check on all the intents you want your bot to have. Like over here:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `command.Bot` after defining the intents :

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True
intents.guilds = True
intents.messages = True
intents.reactions = True
intents.presences = True
intents.message_content = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```